# Скрипт плавного перехода - постепенное появление

Tags: html, javascript

Здравия желаю всем. Проблема такая: на сайт вставил скрипт плавного перехода наверх страницы. Но внизу длинной страницы он не очень удобен. Товарищи, кто может подсказать яваскрипт, чтобы кнопка перехода наверх появлялась постепенно при прокрутке страницы вниз. Я ещё не очень соображаю в JS и буду очень благодарен тому, кто поможет. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А что Вы имеете в виду, Вам нужно чтобы кнопка перехода была всегда в определенном месте экрана независимо от степени прокрутки или чтобы ее прозрачность зависела от степени прокрутки?

Comment: Вот здесь [**ссылка**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647871/234502)  я написал код для такой кнопки на чистом javascript.

Answer (score 3):

[Кнопка "Наверх" как ВКонтакте](http://shublog.ru/ajax/jquery/kak-sdelat-knopku-naverkh-kak-vkontakte/) - точно то, что нужно.